# Create a matrix based in Objects Class acquire by Class Loader method

Tags: java, reflection

In my code, I load class in `.loadClass` method. This work.

```
NewUnit = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
```

Now I need create a matrix based of instances of this class, like this:

```
NewUnit[][] units = new NewUnit[8][5];
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int...)` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int...-), as in:

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(NewUnit, 8, 5)
```

Also, it is customary to name your variables using lower (not upper) camel case.

Comment: It's works. Thank you.

But, how acces the methods of the objects add in this array?

For example: `NewUnit newUnit = this.array[1][1]`

`newUnit.method();´` 

Thanks